# Firefox isnt displaying the Background correctly

Tags: html, css, firefox

following problem. I created a simple hero-unit, and want to give it a nice background. So far so good. Now, when showing it in Chrome I have no problems and it is fitting to all size. Using Mozilla Firefox I only the picture in its true size, repeating to the left and down. Whats wrong guys?

```
    .hero .landing {
    background:url(../images/header.png);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  height:550px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
```

I am thankful for all kind of help!

Comment: You're missing the standard `background-size` property!

Comment: You might want `background-position: center;` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   .hero .landing {background:url(../images/header.png) no-repeat;background-size:cover; -webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;height:550px;}
```

Comment: you didn't give the actual background size so it caused problem. i can give a suggestion that for cross browser support you can use prifixmycss.com to make the codes cross-browser supported. Please mark the ans as correct.